# Boundary conditions for LC circuit with a battery

Tags: capacitance, inductance

Suppose we have a capacitor(C), an inductor(L) and a battery, all in series. Switch is closed at t=0. We can write the differential equation by Kirchhoff's loop rule and it's solution is a function of current which is a sine function. But where do I get the boundary conditions from like maximum current? Maximum charge? Also what is the order of events and why does it even oscillate?

Comment: If talking about a battery (DC source), then the solution you find won't be a sine function.

Comment: The equation would be V- q/C - Ldi/dt=0. Differentiate. -i/LC=d^2i/dt^2. You can compare this to the differential equation of simple harmonic oscillator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out, the general solution is an oscillation : $i(t)=A\sin(\omega t)+B\cos(\omega t)$ with $\omega^2=1/LC$.

Initially there will be no current $i(0)=0$ because the inductor resists changes of current, and there was none before the switch was closed. So we must have $B=0$ hence $i(t)=A\sin(\omega t)$.

Since there is no current initially, the capacitor is also uncharged intially. The PD across the capacitor is zero, while the PD across the inductor is that of the battery, $V$. The initial PD across the inductor is $Ldi/dt=L\omega A cos(\omega t)$ at $t=0$, so $L\omega A=V$ which provides the value for $A$.